# PL/SQL Trigger Mutating Table on compound trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

writing a trigger on table that updates another table on oracle 
trigger throws mutating table error.
I know the error is coming because i am updating the table that is reference in my row level block but i cannot figure out a work around

EDIT: This code throws a PL/SQL: numeric or value error: NULL index table key value but i seem to have gotten around the mutating table.

```
create or replace TRIGGER DSPLATE_WELL_VOLUME_V3
FOR UPDATE ON DSPLATE 
COMPOUND TRIGGER


TYPE t_PLATE_ID IS TABLE OF DSPLATE.PLATE_ID%TYPE;
v_PLATE_ID  t_PLATE_ID;
TYPE t_NEW_AMOUNT IS TABLE OF DSPLATE.AMOUNT%TYPE;
v_NEW_AMOUNT  t_NEW_AMOUNT;


BEFORE STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    v_PLATE_ID := t_PLATE_ID();
    v_NEW_AMOUNT := t_NEW_AMOUNT();
END BEFORE STATEMENT;


BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.PLATE_TYPE != :OLD.PLATE_TYPE AND :NEW.PLATE_TYPE = 'Assay Plate' 
      AND :NEW.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NULL THEN
           v_PLATE_ID(v_PLATE_ID.LAST) := :OLD.PLATE_ID;
           v_NEW_AMOUNT(v_NEW_AMOUNT.LAST) := :NEW.AMOUNT_INITIAL;
  END IF;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    FOR p IN 1..v_PLATE_ID.LAST LOOP
                  UPDATE DSPLATE_WELL
            SET AMOUNT = AMOUNT - v_NEW_AMOUNT(p)
              WHERE WELL_ID IN (SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_ID
              FROM DSPLATE INNER JOIN DSPLATE_WELL ON DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE.PLATE_ID
              WHERE DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE IN (SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE
              FROM DSPLATE_WELL INNER JOIN DSPLATE ON DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID WHERE DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = v_PLATE_ID(p))
              AND DSPLATE.PLATE_TYPE = 'Cherry Pick Plate' AND DSPLATE.LOCATION_ID = 1420);
        END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;


END;
```

The original trigger i wrote that worked is this but I want it to be written as a compound trigger instead, when a plate_type is set to 'assay plate' the query looks up all well_values of that plate_id on table DSPLATE_WELL, the well_values correspond back to many different plate_ids on table DSPLATE with plate_type 'cherry pick' and specific WELL_IDs where the WELL_VALUES originally came from must have their volume amount updated.

```
create or replace TRIGGER INSERT_DSPLATE_WELL_VOLUME 
AFTER UPDATE ON DSPLATE  
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
pragma autonomous_transaction;


BEGIN
  IF :NEW.PLATE_TYPE != :OLD.PLATE_TYPE AND :NEW.PLATE_TYPE = 'Assay Plate' 
AND :NEW.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NULL
  THEN
      UPDATE DSPLATE_WELL
        SET AMOUNT = AMOUNT - :NEW.AMOUNT_INITIAL
          WHERE WELL_ID IN (SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_ID
          FROM DSPLATE INNER JOIN DSPLATE_WELL ON DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE.PLATE_ID
          WHERE DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE IN (SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE
          FROM DSPLATE_WELL INNER JOIN DSPLATE ON DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID WHERE DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = :OLD.PLATE_ID)
          AND DSPLATE.PLATE_TYPE = 'Cherry Pick Plate' AND DSPLATE.LOCATION_ID = 1420);
          COMMIT;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I can't immediately see what the code is meant to do from looking at the (unformatted) code. Why do you have to query the table while it is being updated?

Comment: I explain how the code works in my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace TRIGGER DSPLATE_WELL_VOLUME_V3
FOR UPDATE ON DSPLATE 
COMPOUND TRIGGER



TYPE t_PLATE_ID IS TABLE OF DSPLATE.PLATE_ID%TYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
v_PLATE_ID  t_PLATE_ID;
v_NEW_AMOUNT t_PLATE_ID;

counter number := 1;


BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.PLATE_TYPE != :OLD.PLATE_TYPE AND :NEW.PLATE_TYPE = 'Assay Plate' 
      AND :NEW.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NULL THEN
           v_PLATE_ID(counter) := :OLD.PLATE_ID;
           v_NEW_AMOUNT(counter) := :NEW.AMOUNT_INITIAL;
           counter := counter + 1;
  END IF;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    FOR p IN 1..v_PLATE_ID.COUNT LOOP
                  UPDATE DSPLATE_WELL
            SET AMOUNT = AMOUNT - v_NEW_AMOUNT(p)
              WHERE WELL_ID IN (SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_ID
              FROM DSPLATE INNER JOIN DSPLATE_WELL ON DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE.PLATE_ID
              WHERE DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE IN (SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE
              FROM DSPLATE_WELL INNER JOIN DSPLATE ON DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID WHERE DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = v_PLATE_ID(p))
              AND DSPLATE.PLATE_TYPE = 'Cherry Pick Plate' AND DSPLATE.LOCATION_ID = 1420 AND DSPLATE_WELL.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL);
        END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;


END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger should look like this one:

```
create or replace TRIGGER DSPLATE_WELL_VOLUME_V2
FOR UPDATE ON DSPLATE 
COMPOUND TRIGGER

TYPE t_WELL_ID IS TABLE OF DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_ID%TYPE;
v_WELL_ID  t_WELL_ID := t_WELL_ID();
TYPE t_AMOUNT IS TABLE OF INT;
v_NEW_AMOUNT t_AMOUNT := t_AMOUNT();



TYPE t_PLATE_ID IS TABLE OF DSPLATE.PLATE_ID%TYPE;
v_PLATE_ID  t_PLATE_ID;


BEFORE STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    v_PLATE_ID := t_PLATE_ID();
END BEFORE STATEMENT;


BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.PLATE_TYPE != :OLD.PLATE_TYPE AND :NEW.PLATE_TYPE = 'Assay Plate' 
      AND :NEW.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NOT NULL AND :OLD.AMOUNT_INITIAL IS NULL THEN
           v_PLATE_ID.EXTEND;
           v_PLATE_ID(v_PLATE_ID.LAST) := :OLD.PLATE_ID;
  END IF;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN

FOR p IN 1..v_PLATE_ID.LAST LOOP

    SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_ID, :NEW.AMOUNT
    BULK COLLECT INTO v_WELL_ID, v_NEW_AMOUNT
    FROM DSPLATE INNER JOIN DSPLATE_WELL ON DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE.PLATE_ID
    WHERE DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE IN 
          (SELECT DSPLATE_WELL.WELL_VALUE
          FROM DSPLATE_WELL INNER JOIN DSPLATE ON DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = DSPLATE_WELL.PLATE_ID 
          WHERE DSPLATE.PLATE_ID = v_PLATE_ID(p))
       AND DSPLATE.PLATE_TYPE = 'Cherry Pick Plate' 
       AND DSPLATE.LOCATION_ID = 1420;

    FOR i in 1..v_WELL_ID.count() LOOP
      UPDATE DSPLATE_WELL SET AMOUNT = (AMOUNT - v_NEW_AMOUNT(i)) 
      WHERE WELL_ID = v_WELL_ID(i);
    END LOOP;

END LOOP;


END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
```

Note, this code is not tested and most likely not optimal in terms of performance (I assume the second loop is not required and can be put in a single UPDATE statement). However, you should get an idea how compound triggers are working.

Comment: I see the direction you are going in but this still contains a :NEW bind on the statement level, this throws a bind error when trying to compile

Answer (score 0):

I had written similar compound triggers and I used "before statement" to catch the values (I had used a SELECT to fill a structure with bulk collect) and "after each row" to update.